# Image is not showing on created PDF using DOMPDF on localserver

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am created PDF using DOMPdf Every thing showing properly but image is not

showing.

```
<?php   
$data1.='<p>Peace,</p><image src="http://localhost/manresaorg/im_Steve-Raymond-1.jpg"></p>Steve Raymond
<br>Associate Director';
$data1.='</main></div>';
?>
<?php 

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    // reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($data1);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
//$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
//$dompdf->stream("manresaorg.pdf");
$dompdf->stream("manresaorg.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

exit(0);

?>
```

I tried absolute path like:->

```
<image src="E:\xampp\htdocs\manresaorg\im_Steve-Raymond-1.jpg">
```

But it is not showing image on PDF.I am using Xampp Server on window.

Comment: Try with binary format

Comment: @Niklesh binary formate ?

Comment: if you open pdf may be some how you can see image because you image in your `e: drive` but what happen if I will open that pdf. So i suggest use binary form of image, first search to convert image in binary format and then assign it to src attribute in img tag.

Comment: I suspect that you can also use the data image url format, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: surely you are not using a valid HTML img element? Shouldn't it be: `$data1.='<p>Peace,</p><img src="http://localhost/manresaorg/im_Steve-Raymond-1.jpg"></p>Steve Raymond
<br>Associate Director';`?